# How to prevent grinding?

Tags: game-design

I am making an investment game where the goal is to have a lot of money from a little as fast as possible. There are banks with join fees and maximum balances.

I added sleeping, which skips to 8:00 the next day, with 22:00 being the bedtime

I want for a savings account to be an invest option, and I ran into a loophole. If you just invest the starting money and sleep till you get max money in the savings account and keep upgrading the bank, you can get infinite money with just spamming sleep for hours, or even using an auto-typer.

While the goal is to make a fortune as fast as possible, I still want to get rid of that loophole. Bills and energy are too complex, and I want to keep both the game and the code relatively simple, without adding inflation.

**Should I just remove saving accounts, or is there a simple solution (or reverse psychology) to grinding I am missing?**

Is there a physiological approach?

*EDIT: This is a single-player text-based game.*

*Each bank has a join fee, max loan, and max balance. Upgrading bank will take around 75% of max money of the previous bank, making "levels". Maybe I will put better savings accounts for bigger banks and add a credit score.*

*I will also add investments like company startup loans, lottery and stock*

*You can only do the following things:*

- Invest
- Change bank
- Wait
- Buy things like caffeine pills to extend bedtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several options to remedy this, all involving the end goal of the game which you did not state in your question:

- Add an ingame time limit of a few years. Savings accounts will just be too slow to increase wealth significantly in the short time.
- Make the end goal purchasing a certain asset, and make the cost of this asset rise with inflation or faster, at least faster than the savings interest. Savings accounts will not help you if the goal moves faster than the savings over time.
- Make the end goal being significantly wealthier than some AI opponents. The opponents should be able to profit faster than the savings account.

The common feature of all these options is that the goal of the game, making money "as fast as possible", should be measured by ingame time, not playtime.

Comment: The goal as I stated in the question, it to have a certain amount of money as fast as you can, and I don't want a time limit as if you fail with sticks or anything, you can always have a way back.

Comment: If you want no ingame time limitation, and you want a "skip to next day" option, and you want to enable savings accounts which work towards the goal, but you *don't* want autoclick-to-win, then the only option you have is to change your mind.

Answer (score 0):

Implement inflation.

In the real world, money just sitting in an account loses buying power over time.
Inflation should be simulated in any game that tries to make a realistic impression of real world investing. You can see [here](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/CPIAUCSL) that the Consumer Price Index has steadily risen year after year, so $1 gets you less year after year.

A normal low-risk/low-interest savings account will lose buying power over time due to inflation removing value faster than interest can add value.

So, if the player just puts $1000 in an account and sleeps 365x in a row, they *should* earn the interest rate for 1 year, but the new balance in the account is now less useful than the $1000 that they had 1 year ago.

Comment: Inflation is too complex and long for me to implement, and I want to keep it simple.

Comment: You can implement a simple divisor for how much $1.00 is worth that increases by a random amount every year/month/day.
So `adjusted_balance = (1.00 / inflation) * balance`, and you use `adjusted_balance` to measure the success of the player instead of the raw `balance`. As a joke you could measure the player's score in terms of [how many burgers they can afford](https://www.statista.com/statistics/274326/big-mac-index-global-prices-for-a-big-mac/).

Comment: Expanding on this idea, you can even designate formulas to make sure the inflation only goes up at the end of the day, it would be pretty funny to see the results of a very long period.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to remove the saving account option. The direct path to simplicity is to remove things. Now, I believe you don't want that solution. Thus, you will have to accept some level of complexity.

---

I'll mention an hypothetical scenario here. Don't worry, I'll come back the topic at hand.

The hypothetical scenario: Alice lends some money to Bob, who agrees to pay back in some months plus some extra. Bob uses the money to buy some machines and materials so he can start a - let us say - a bike repair shop. After a while Bob got the money back and then some, so he pays what he owes to to Alice.

This is one of the simplest scenarios for an investment. There is no intermediaries, no taxes, no stock exchange, no minting, no reserve baking…

And it suggest a couple things:

- The person getting a loan must be able to get a return on investment faster than the person lending.
- The return on investment may take some time.

---

Alright, back to the topic at hand. We will keep the saving account, and it will be an investment option. However, as the hypothetical scenario suggests:

- You are going to add the option to get a loan.
- You are going to add other things in which the player can invest, but they imply some risk.

Such that just putting money on the saving account is actually the slow option, but also the safe (risk-free) option.

---

Which remind me, you say the game is about getting money fast, you don't want a time limit, and you want a time skip option.

So, I suggest to not allow to skip to the next day if the day just started. And thus push people to do something else while they wait for nightfall.

Furthermore, if this is a multiplayer game, perhaps you should remove the time skip option altogether.

---

By the way, about the risk. I don't mean gambling. I'm not encouraging to create a casino-like game. Perhaps in a different kind of game I would add skill based mini (or perhaps no so mini) games, and depending on how the player does, they get more or less money.

However, let's us think how can we do this differently… Instead of requiring player skill, we are going to simulate skill. Thus: leveling.

That is, the player will gain level in doing whatever it is they do to get money. *I don't know what they do to get money in the game.* So the more they do or invest on an activity/job/company, the more levels they get. And the more levels they have, the more money they get (as in, the same amount invested will pay back more).

Except putting money on the saving account. That does not level up. It is always the same return on investment. *Wait, is that what you mean by "upgrading the bank"? If so, yeah, remove that.*

And thus, in the long run, leveling up is the best way to get money fast, because it accelerates, while putting money in the saving account has constant speed.

By the way, I say leveling, but it does not have to be called that. For example, it could be that you invest in a company, and the company goes over different stages of growth. Or if it is a job, then it is that they get promotions. For some activities you could say it is mastery. Or for other activities it could be reputation or popularity.

---

Again, I don't know how your game works. However, I suppose return on investment could have variability. For example some investments could be seasonal. Or it might depend on the popularity of a company or product, or something like that. And thus, in an investment game you could give hints to the player of what to invest on in the form of news. That way, investing in the best option remains skill based.

---

Or you could be going for an idle game/auto-clicker. In which case remove the time skip option.

*I don't know. I might be imagining a completely different game than what you have.*

Comment: Let me clarify: This is a single-player text-based game. Each bank has a join fee, max loan, and max balance. Upgrading bank will take around 75% of max money of the previous bank, making "levels". Maybe I will put better savings accounts for bigger banks and add a credit score.

Comment: I edited the question with more details also

Comment: Well as the goal is to make it "In the least days possible", I decided to do nothing. I am going for a simple realistic game (without that inflation), and you can put money in a bank  and live your life and then open it like a piggy bank. But I will put a 100 year time limit, something like "You died of old age"

Comment: @Leo I didn't propose inflation. That was Romen answer. Adding a time limit was Magma idea, so I think you should accept that answer. Mine was along the lines of making saving not that good in comparison to investment.

Comment: Still, thank you for making a long and detailed answer.